# Migrating data from PostgreSQL to Oracle along with the constraints

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-migration

I have successfully migrated data (test schema) from PostgreSQL to Oracle using the PostgreSQL drivers.

All the tables are migrated but the constraints are not reflected in Oracle.
My question is how migrate the constraints along with the tables.
I am using windows 7 OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code that does the migration.

Comment: i havent used any code for migration.
i installed PostgreSQL drivers in SQLdeveloper. Then the database which is in postgres will automatically reflect in Oracle. i have then copied it to Oracle.